# Vb.Net in Enterprice Solution Like MvvM , Framework samples

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, frameworks

I tiered From searching for good method for developing database Project in Vb.net.
jumping from winform to lightswitch to wpf... with problems in each other
I see the net fill with Framework from other Languages that can easily start with database application. while we are suffering to find solution for report in lightswitch or converting the code from C# examples..

please Advice Me if I have to change to other Programing Language or if there is good "Data-framework" Project that I can join.
with best regard

Answer (score 0):

Vb.net is good for creating database applications.  Try some simple examples.  This code will load your SQL query into a datatable, using parameters:
Your SQL code will look like this "SELECT col1, col2 FROM tablename WHERE  col1 = @param1"  You need to add @param1 and its value to criteria.

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

```
 Public Function LoadDB(ByVal MySQL As String, ByVal Criteria As Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    conn.ConnectionString = EFACSConnection

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        For Each myKey As String In Criteria.Keys
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(myKey, Criteria(myKey))
        Next
        cmd.CommandText = MySQL
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        adapter.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        dt = New DataTable("Empty")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: "simple example", what about MvvM,

Comment: How about this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level